# Illustrator: Grain Effect makes round objects pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, illustration, texture

I would like to apply an effect to the whole artboard (all elements), so that the colors don't look too monotone.

It should look like [this](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/hd/e820cb31813937.5662fb792b1c7.jpg) (found it [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/31813937/Cosmos-Muertos)):

[image]

I think this effect is called Grain. So I selected all elements in my artboard and went Effect > Texture > Grain.

Now I have two problems:

**(1)** Round objects look pixelated

This is how it looks in Illustrator:
[image]

When I export it, it looks better, but still more pixelated than without the grain effect:

[image]

**(2)** The file size increases enormously

Without the grain effect the picture with circle and rectangle has 7KB. With the effect 326KB.

**Question:**

How can I solve these two problems? Should I export it without an effect, and apply it in another program? And is this effect even called grain?

Summarized: What should I do to get the same effect like in the referenced picture, while keeping a "small" export size and having smooth round objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Create a new layer above your artwork.

[image]

### 2. Create a shape over the whole artboard (or the area you want the texture applied to).

### 3. Apply your Grain (Effects → Texture → Grain).

[image]

### 4. With your textured shape selected, open the transparency palette (Window → Transparency) and change the blending mode.

Different blending modes will have different results. I suggest starting with *Multiply*.

[image]

You can use whatever color layer you want, white will work but I usually go for a slight off-white but it completely depends on the effect you want.

If you only want the texture applied to a certain area just mask off the texture.

The file size is increasing because *Grain* is a raster effect, you are basically embedding a raster image in your Illustrator file. You can just as easily (and I often do) create the image in Photoshop (or your preferred image editing program) and place it in your Illustrator file as a linked file. This solves the file size problem, but you now also have 2 files to worry about.

You can achieve the same effect by using a [textured image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=texture&tbm=isch).

Comment: Or use gray and overlay

Comment: overlay messes with colors too much in my experience—but, yes. endless possibilities with a mixture of different colors, blending modes and opacity levels etc etc etc.

Comment: If you have a exact mid tone gray (127,127,127 in rgb mode) then you will end up with the same effect as applying the effect on the object itself without rasterization.

Comment: Great solution! I would like to add though that, if someone wants to export as SVG (which I was), then it’s probably not a good idea to have textures, because it turns it into raster and looks weird. So, in that case using a PNG (2× or 3×) is a better solution!